# Does play framework 2.0 support nested if statement in template?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Does play framework 2.0 support nested if statement in template ?

I using the following code, but the rendered html is this ""

// template

```
<tr class=@if(e.error1!=""){"error"} 
        else if(e.statusDetail.contains("failure")){"warning"} 
        else{"info"} >
```

// generated html

```
<tr class= 
        else if(e.statusDetail.contains("failure")){"warning"} 
        else{"info"} >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is unsupported: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/783-else-if-statement-missing-in-the-scala-template

You can use pattern matching or if bolck inside else.