# Does Playframework 2.0.x support <else if> in templates

Tags: playframework

I wonder if play 2.0.3 and higher supports `else if` in views? I only read that one have to code that way: `if {...}else{if{...}else{...}}`  cannot believe that.

Comment: Now it's supported. You need to use latest playframework. https://github.com/playframework/twirl/issues/33

Answer (score 35):

I used an @ before the second if :

```
@if (true) {
...
} else { @if (true) {
...
} else {
...
}}
```

Comment: For me, the @if() can't have a space.

Comment: warning: the "else" must be on the same line as the previous closing bracket (yes...seriously, sigh...)

Comment: @AdrienBe oh yes, this got my head spinning for quite a while

Answer (score 29):

The @Todd Flanders answer is right. In a wrapper @{}, you can write your normal Scala code. Example

```
@{
  if (profile.sex == 0) {
    <p class="col-md-6">Other</p>
  } else if (profile.sex == 1) {
    <p class="col-md-6">Male</p>
  } else {
    <p class="col-md-6">Female</p>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the best answer ever. Why you guys did not vote up this answer?

Comment: I agree that this is the most sane solution to the problem.

Answer (score 16):

I was also able to get

```
@{if (true) "foo" else if (true) "bar" else "baz"}
```

to work.  Keep in mind that most programming languages do not support "else if" as a lexical token.  They are separate commands.  The block of code executed by the "else" command happens to be an "if" statement.

Note also that you can mix XHTML with the clause:

```
 @{if (true) <b>foo</b> else if (false) "bar" else "baz"}
```

I agree with biesior that it's usually a good idea to push state logic into the controller, then you can have different views for different states, with shared components having their own sub-views.

Answer (score 10):

No, it doesn't. It allows you only for `if(condition) {then...} else {otherwise...}`

For more possibilities you need to use [Pattern Matching](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates) (similar to PHP's `switch()`)

In this case `_` is a default option.

Sample from previous version of Play Autheticate (now the same is done with reflections in the controller)

```
@(url: String, token: String, name: String)

@defining(lang().code) { langcode =>

    @langcode match {
        case "de" => {@_password_reset_de(url,token,name)}
        case "pl" => {@_password_reset_pl(url,token,name)}
        case _ => {@_password_reset_en(url,token,name)}
    }

}
```

So maybe best option for you will be resolving the condition in the controller and passing it as a param to the view?

Answer (score 3):

Now `if else if` is supported in latest playframework. Discussion is here https://github.com/playframework/twirl/issues/33

You can use like this:

```
@if(something) {
  ...
} else if (somethingElse) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it was released? I'm using `2.5.14` and this still wont compile (I copied your example and replaced conditions with `true` and dots with `<br/>`. Or maybe am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No, "else if" is not supported in scala templates: [Does play framework 2.0 support nested if statement in template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945916/does-play-framework-2-0-support-nested-if-statement-in-template/13946078#13946078)

You can use pattern matching or you can put if inside else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch statement` in `Scala` to achieve it.

Example:

```
if(x>2){
   <block 1>

} else if(x>0) {
   <block 2>

} else {
   <block 3>
}
```

Translated:

```
x match {
   case x if(x>2) => {<block 1>}
   case x if(x>0) => {<block 2>}
   case _ => {<block 3>}
}
```

Hope can help you in some cases and hope play framework will support `else if` soon.