# Use of #{if-else} tags in PLAY templates

Tags: html, templates, playframework

I am working since last few months with PLAY 1.2.5 using Java and HTML for views. I am aware of using JAVA code in PLAY templates using `%{ if ------else}%` (kind of as we use scriplets in J2EE. But now I came across use of tags like `#{if}---{/if}`. I searched around and found that this also is a way of using if-else. But my query is that in a similar piece of code I saw the following:

```
#{if some variable value in Controller == 'true'} ------- #{/if} #{else}------ #{/else} .
```

Now I don't understand how this Controller variable is accessed in controller within these tags. I have looked around and found that no such variable was rendered by `render()` or `renderArgs()` from the controller.

Is there any other way of using those variables/methods on templates which are declared in controllers or model for that matter?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074590/does-playframework-2-0-x-support-else-if-in-templates)

Comment: The link provides ways of using @if -else with UI variables. What I was looking for is use of #if-else with controller variables in views.